# Celery task not getting aborted using AbortableTask

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a long running celery task. I want to terminate/stop/revoke that task if user hits /cancel route. I used multiple ways of doing this, but none of them worked. I am using **RabbitMQ** as a message broker.

I have defined a view called "cancel_task" which receives "task_id" from the request parameters.

But, my task is not aborted despite it getting request properly.

Can somebody tell me how to terminate/cancel/stop this task?

Even after cancelling task, this task does not stop executing.

I referred to this document - [Abort celery task example](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html#usage-example)

[image] task.py

[image] views.py

[image] Imports in views.py

[image] Imports in task.py

Output -

[image]